# Python - Sorting with saved sorting order

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, class, sorting

I am very basic in python and I faced a little problem, which I can`t see the solution for that:

I have a list of class `Player` which has:

```py
class player:
    def __init__(self,name,wins,points):
        self.name = name
        self.wins = wins
        self.points = points
```

later after making a list with data i need to sort in specific order:

- Sort in descending by `wins`
- If draw in `wins` sort descending by `points`
- If draw in `points` sort ascending by `name`

I tried next variant of solution (which failed):

```py
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.points)
players.reverse()
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.wins)
players.reverse()
```

but after this i had a little problem with order (while `wins` are equal)... For example:

I have next data:

```py
list({name:"Artur", points:20, wins:1},
     {name:"Jan", points:25, wins:1},
     {name:"Karol", points:10, wins:0})
```

after sorting I need to have next order:

```
Jan
Artur
Karol
```

but that solution that i made sorts partly wrong:
Result:

```
Artur
Jan
Karol
```

*Why partly?* Before final reverse it has right order:

```py
"Karol"
"Jan"   #\this group
"Artur" #/ is in right positions
```

So there is some solution for that? Or maybe I just "*Can`t find a solution from Internet*"-man?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do it with one sort and using a lambda function by returning a tuple:

```
players.sort(key=lambda x: (-x.wins, -x.points, x.name))
```

Note that negative values are used to effect sort by descending values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are using lambda for this, but you need to add conditions to find if two players have equal points, if those conditions match then run an additional sort, then have another conditional for the final sort. Right now you are just sorting everything with the last condition on your list. You'll likely have to use a forloop to check next value against current value in the class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry for interrupting, but i finded the solution by myself...
That was simple changing the position of 1 line:

```py
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.name)
players.reverse() #this one...
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.points)
players.sort(key=lambda x: x.wins)
players.reverse()
```

Again, sorry for interrupt...